# How to use same User form component in VueJS 2 for both create and edit User?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Currently I have separate components `CreateUser.vue` and `EditUser.vue` with very big form.

- Route for `CreateUser` is `/users`
- Route for `EditUser` is `/users/:username`.

The backend API is also different:

- POST for create (`example.com/users`) and
- PUT for edit (`example.com//users/:username`).

Also in `EditUser`, `username` field is **readonly** as it cannot be edited once created otherwise both `CreateUser` and `EditUser` templates are same but Javascript part is different.

**Question:**

How **can I combine this into one Component** `UserForm.vue` and eliminate `CreateUser.vue` and `EditUser.vue` ?

In the main UI there is a button `Create User` which routes to `CreateUser` component. In the list of users view, each row has a button `Edit` which routes to `EditUser` component.

I am using Vue router for defining routes similar to below:

```
{
   path: '/users',
   name: 'createUser',
   component: CreateUser
},
{
   path: '/users/:id',
   component: EditUser,
   name: 'editUser'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [pass parameters](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html) into your component via `props` property in router configuration and then use it as in answer above `to render the necessary inputs...`

```
{
  path: '/users',
  name: 'createUser',
  component: UserForm
  props: {editMode: false}
},
{
  path: '/users/:id',
  name: 'editUser'
  component: UserForm,
  props: {editMode: true}
}
```

Comment: The how do you use '/users to load a list of users if it's mapped on createUser?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a property on your **UserForm.vue**

```js
props: {
    currentAction : {
        type : String,
        default: 'create',
        required: true
    },
},
```

you'll have to pass this string at

```js
<user-form :currentAction="create"></user-form>
```

And in your component use it to call the necessary method createUser() or updateUser(). Also use it to render the necessary inputs and or calculate the necessary computed properties.

By what i see, this property will have to be a data property on your **Main UI** you'll have to change this property before you show the user-form.